# Polymer paper-tooltip

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I need to learn Polymer.js for a project I got assigned to and I'm trying to do some tutorials.

I'm trying to use the paper-tooltip element and have created the following code, but for some reason the tooltip appears but there is no text visible.

FYI: They are still using Polymer 2.0 and I can't change that atm.

Anyone that can spot my error?

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-tooltip/paper-tooltip.html">

<dom-module id="app-root">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <h2>Hello [[prop1]]!</h2>

    <div>
      <button id="btn">Click me!</button>
      <paper-tooltip for="btn" position="bottom">
        Tooltip!!
      </paper-tooltip>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    /**
     * @customElement
     * @polymer
     */
    class AppRoot extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'app-root'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          prop1: {
            type: String,
            value: 'app-root'
          }
        };
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(AppRoot.is, AppRoot);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

    <title>Polymer Test Environment</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Polymer Test">

    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">

    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

    <link rel="import" href="/src/app-root/app-root.html">

    <style>
      body {
        height: 100vh
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For me a pretty similar usage does work, did you check if it's not some CSS issue, like the text having the same colour as the background? Btw, my exact use case, if you want to debug, is `<paper-tooltip fit-to-visible-bounds animation-delay="0" offset="8" for="btn" position="top">`

Comment: doesn't seem to work and I removed all my CSS but still no success. I will try some things out later today and hopefully I can find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem running your code. The app shows up with the button and the tooltip.

Some tips:

- Don't import `polymer.html` in `index.html`. If you want, do so in the components import.
- Be careful with the URL you import. A `/` in the first place will become an absolute path (making it to import from the root).
- Use `webcomponents-lite.js` instead of `webcomponents-loader.js`. The only case `webcomponents-loader.js` makes a difference is when it is used with `async`. Otherwise, simply load all the polyfills.

Here's the working project I have uploaded to Github. I am not sure how you structure it so I just include them in all the root folder. I only modified the import codes, everything else stays the same.

https://github.com/binhbbbb/app-root

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will look at it when I'm home later today. Thanks for the git repo with a solution.